# Raspberry pi DSRC

Tags: wifi

i want to implement DSRC on the raspberry board as i know DSRC( dedicated short range communication) uses frequency range 5.84-5.96 GHz. But i am thinking if i can do it by enabling dual mode by 5GHz on pi board. This can be done via manipulation of PHy and MAc layer changes in the wireless driver file of that board or module.

https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8070033/references#references https://github.com/jfpastrana/802.11p/blob/master/Documentation/802.11p_standard_and_V2X_applications.pdf

i am assuming it can also be done in the board. can anyone please tell me how to do that or where can i find the wireless drivers.